# Create a Monthly Report Procedure in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

Ok this is a tricky one (for me at least) lets say I have the following tables--
TABLES

`ORDERS`

```
create table orders (
ono      number(5) not null primary key,
cno      number(5) references customers,
eno      number(4) references employees,
received date,
shipped  date);
```

`ODETAILS`

```
create table odetails (
ono      number(5) not null references orders,
pno      number(5) not null references parts,
qty      integer check(qty > 0),
primary key (ono,pno));
```

`PARTS`

```
create table parts(
pno      number(5) not null primary key,
pname    varchar2(30),
qoh      integer check(qoh >= 0),
price    number(6,2) check(price >= 0.0),
olevel   integer);
```

TABLES DATA

```
insert into orders values
  (1020,1111,1000,'10-DEC-11','12-DEC-11');
insert into orders values
  (1021,1111,1000,'12-JAN-12','15-JAN-12');
insert into orders values
  (1022,2222,1001,'13-FEB-12','20-FEB-12');
insert into orders values
  (1023,3333,1000,'12-MAR-12',null);
insert into odetails values
  (1020,10506,1);
insert into odetails values
  (1020,10507,1);
insert into odetails values
  (1020,10508,2);
insert into odetails values
  (1020,10509,3);
insert into odetails values
  (1021,10601,4);
insert into odetails values
  (1022,10601,1);
insert into odetails values
  (1022,10701,1);
insert into odetails values
  (1023,10800,1);
insert into odetails values
  (1023,10900,1);
insert into parts values
  (10506,'Land Before Time I',200,19.99,20);
insert into parts values
  (10507,'Land Before Time II',156,19.99,20);
insert into parts values
  (10508,'Land Before Time III',190,19.99,20); 
insert into parts values
  (10509,'Land Before Time IV',60,19.99,20);
insert into parts values
  (10601,'Sleeping Beauty',300,24.99,20);
insert into parts values
  (10701,'When Harry Met Sally',120,19.99,30);
insert into parts values
  (10800,'Dirty Harry',140,14.99,30);
insert into parts values
  (10900,'Dr. Zhivago',100,24.99,30);
```

Now I'm required to create a procedure which takes in a value as month and generates a report which contains the following--

`a.`    Number of sales
`b.`    Sales value
`c.`    Most popular item
`d.`    Least popular item

My approach

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_REPORT
(MONTH_NUMBER IN NUMBER )


AS

PARTS_NUMBER VARCHAR2(10);
SHIPPING_STATUS VARCHAR2(10);
V_ENO VARCHAR2(5);
V_PNO VARCHAR2(5);
SALES NUMBER(30);
V_MONTH VARCHAR2(10);


BEGIN


SELECT RECEIVED INTO V_MONTH FROM ORDERS  WHERE  
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ORDERS.RECEIVED) = MONTH_NUMBER;

SELECT SUM(PRICE*QTY)
INTO SALES
FROM ORDERS,ODETAILS,PARTS
WHERE  
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ORDERS.RECEIVED) = MONTH_NUMBER
END TEST_REPORT;
```

Then bang my head explodes. I was thinking of using cursors.. but then I thought a `SELECT` query with different column alias would be simpler. But as it seems I cant get the syntax right and currently If I execute this procedure it gives me a an error
`ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows`

As there is more than one record in the table. What approach would be right and logical? and also did I get the syntax right for the procedures? I would appreciate the help and guidance.
Many thanks
(P.S. I condemn the person's naming convention in the script which I had to run to create the tables)

Comment: Why are you using `TO_DATE(ORDERS.RECEIVED...` when ORDERS.RECEIVED is defined as DATE?

Comment: Hi Bob.. I've edited the post

Comment: Number of order cancellations and value, number of returns and values, item that has highest return: there does not appear to be data in the question (at this point) which would supply this information. Please edit your question and either add information to the question which could be used to derive this data, or explain how the existing data would supply this information. Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis Yes tables that hold the `Number of order cancellations and value, number of returns and values, item that has highest return` are not included in this question so I'll remove them. The question is too broad as it is at the moment so I'll refrain from cluttering it any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's see:

Number of sales (I'm assuming "of each part"):

```
SELECT od.PNO, COUNT(*) AS SALE_COUNT
  FROM ODETAILS od
  INNER JOIN ORDERS o
    ON od.ONO = o.ONO
  WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM o.RECEIVED) = &MONTH_NUMBER
  GROUP BY od.PNO
```

Sales value:

```
SELECT od.PNO, p.PRICE, SUM(od.QTY) AS SALES_QTY, SUM(od.QTY * p.PRICE) AS SALES_VALUE
  FROM ODETAILS od
  INNER JOIN PARTS p
    ON p.PNO = od.PNO
  GROUP BY od.PNO, p.PRICE
```

Most popular item (just take the first row):

```
SELECT od.PNO, SUM(od.QTY) AS TOTAL_QTY
  FROM ODETAILS od
  GROUP BY od.PNO
  ORDER BY SUM(od.QTY) DESC
```

Least popular item (which has any sales) (just take the first row):

```
SELECT od.PNO, SUM(od.QTY) AS TOTAL_QTY
  FROM ODETAILS od
  GROUP BY od.PNO
  ORDER BY SUM(od.QTY) ASC
```

Number of order cancellations and value, number of returns and values, item that has highest return: there does not appear to be data in the question (at this point) which would supply this information. I'll add a comment to the question to this effect. If further information or explanations are forthcoming I'll include this in my answer.

Best of luck.

Comment: Hey Bob thanks... I have the scripts to create the whole database and to populate the data.. But I dont know how to upload them here.. should I just post it as a code block?

PS Number of sales equals to multiplication of odetails.qty and parts.price where month = given month in the procedure execution

Comment: You should post all relevant information in the question itself. Thanks.

Comment: Updated.. You are going to love the `PARTS` table data

Comment: And also how do I add WHERE clause to the SQL's mentioned above? All the sql above should only return the data that is based on the month given during procedure call

I tried 

`SELECT od.PNO, p.PRICE, SUM(od.QTY) AS SALES_QTY, SUM(od.QTY * p.PRICE) AS SALES_VALUE
  FROM ODETAILS OD
   WHERE  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ORDERS.RECEIVED) = &MONTH_NUMBER
  INNER JOIN PARTS p
  ON P.PNO = OD.PNO
    
  GROUP BY OD.PNO, P.PRICE;`
But I get 
`Error at Command Line : 4 Column : 3
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

Comment: The `WHERE` clause comes after all the join information, but before `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY`. [See the Oracle SQL Reference manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/toc.htm). I've modified the first query to join in the `ORDERS` table - you can take care of the rest. Best of luck.

Comment: Hi Bob thanks again
What would be the PL?SQL structure? I have tried the following--

`begin
SELECT od.PNO, COUNT(*) AS SALE_COUNT
  FROM ODETAILS od
  INNER JOIN ORDERS o
    ON od.ONO = o.ONO
  WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM O.RECEIVED) = &MONTH_NUMBER
  GROUP BY OD.PNO;
  end;` getting an `ORA-06550` and `PLS-00428` error.

Comment: This is another question - I suggest that you post it as such. Thanks.

Comment: I disagree Bob. My original question and my approach to the problem was a procedure with pl/sql structure.

Comment: 1) I doubt too many people here have the Oracle error codes memorized - I know I certainly do not - nor could we possibly know what the remaining text of the messages are, and that remaining text is rather important. 2) the changes needed to your code are sufficiently extensive that they're not going to fit in a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Both these queries have issues.

Below query will return more than one record from ORDERS table. `INTO` clause will work only when the query returns exactly one record at a time.

```
SELECT RECEIVED INTO V_MONTH FROM ORDERS  WHERE  
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ORDERS.RECEIVED) = MONTH_NUMBER;
```

This query have 2 issues, `no join between ORDERS, ODETAILS and PARTS` as well as `INTO` clause. Here also it will return more than one record.

```
SELECT SUM(PRICE*QTY)
INTO SALES
FROM ORDERS,ODETAILS,PARTS
WHERE  
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ORDERS.RECEIVED) = MONTH_NUMBER
END TEST_REPORT;
```

You need to define your requirement to suggest approach for your application.